# CKeditor show JS scope

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I face a problem  that in  ckeditor JS

```
var msg="hello world ";

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("editor");

editor.setData ('<p> msg <p>');
```

in the  html it just show "msg"  but  i  just want to  show  "hello world",
what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

`editor.setData ('<p>' + msg + '<p>');`

But really, I think you might benefit more from learning JavaScript basics before learning how to use a specific program like CKEditor. This is very very basic stuff I'm afraid.

Comment: +1 for the "learn JS first". Otherwise you won't be able to make any use of the CKEditor API.